# python tkinter Receive variables

Tags: python, tkinter

If the value received from "label3_1_1Spinbox" in an if conditional statement and the value received is of integer type, what should I do if I want to print Save or output an error?

```
    self.C = IntVar()
    self.label3_1_1Spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(frame3,textvariable=self.C)
    self.label3_1_1Spinbox.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nwes")
    self.label3_1_2Spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(frame3)
    self.label3_1_2Spinbox.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nwes")
    self.label3_1_3Spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(frame3)
    self.label3_1_3Spinbox.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="nwes",columnspan=2)




def save(self):
    if type(self.C) == int:
        self.A.configure(text="Error")
    else :
        self.A.configure(text="Saved")
```

Comment: It looks like you already know how to configure the `text` of a `Label` what are you having issues with when trying to `print` or save output error?  Printing something is straight forward so I would need you to clarify how you want to "save" the error information....with `logging`?

Comment: `self.C` is an object. `self.C.get()` returns the value stored in the object.

Comment: i'm finished use try except